# Why is the electric potential zero in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential

The situation: a charge of $-2q$ is situated a distance $r$ to the left of a charge of $q$. What is the electric potential at a point $p$ a distance $r$ to the right of charge $q$?

So basically: -2q -----r-----q-----r-----P

The answer given is that it is zero but I don't see how?

The electric field at $p$ is

$$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{q}{r^2}-\frac{2q}{4r^2}\right)$$

And if you integrate that to get $V = -\int_O^P \vec{E}.d\vec{r}$ the terms in the bracket won't cancel?!

Comment: You're mixing up two $r$'s. The $dr$ in the potential formula is the change in the distance between the charge and the point. For the $-2q$ charge, this is $2r$, so its infinitesimal change is $2 dr$.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption you have to make is that the zero of potential is infinity.
The total work done by unit positive charge in bringing it from infinity to point $P$ is the potential at point $P$.

$$-\int_\infty^r \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{+q}{r^2}\right) dr -\int_\infty^{2r} \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{-2q}{r^2}\right)dr = +\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{q}{r}\right)- \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{2q}{2r}\right) = 0$$

Notice that the upper limit of integration is different for each of the two terms.

Answer (score -1):

The more simple answer, I suspect is: you're looking at the electric field from a point charge ($\sim r^{-2}$) and not the potential, which goes as $r^{-1}$. If you simply write up your formula with potentials instead of electric fields, the answer is immediate.